# what is the main cause of 500 internal server error?

Tags: shared-hosting

I want to know that I have hosted with a hosting company .
My website gives "500 Internal server error many times"
I have following Web server statistics :-

```
Web Server Statistics
Successful requests: 127,310 (7,504)
Average successful requests per day: 814 (1,071)
Successful requests for pages: 24,949 (1,309)
Average successful requests for pages per day: 159 (186)
Failed requests: 3,499 (58)
Redirected requests: 10,091 (114)
Distinct files requested: 5,791 (556)
Distinct hosts served: 5,107 (330)
Data transferred: 4.28 gigabytes (190.56 megabytes)
Average data transferred per day: 28.03 megabytes (27.22 megabytes)
```

Can you tell me my server condition by seeing this or i have to give another details.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you should ask _"Is my hosting provider server powerful enough for described needs?"_. And then [define](http://serverfault.com/posts/440536/edit) those needs.

Comment: depends what your site does? and what @Sampo said is a good indication your don't really know?

Comment: as it has Failed requests: 3,499 (58) is it normal?

Comment: Are you an administrator on this server? Do you have console/command-line access or do you just administer your server through a control panel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

814 requests per day should be easy to serve unless you have a plugin or theme that is doing something really resource intensive.  I would recommend using the "wp super cache" plugin because it will do full page caching and decrease the load your site is putting on the server significantly.

Answer (score 4):

50 unique visitors per day is nothing. You could host that on a cell phone. The "power" of your server is most likely not the problem, though you haven't listed any specs. I suppose if it's running off of a Pentium I with 16MB of RAM you might have a hard time.

Comment: I was actually going to say the same thing about my phone.